# How to run secure voip traffic without using vpn

Tags: vpn, ssl, voip

I use quintum tenor for voip traffic using VPN SSL Tunnel. VPN server is based in another country. VPN used enough bandwidth, and we need to reduce bandwidth consumption. Is there any SECURE way to use quintum without using VPN SSL Tunnel, which should not be traceable by ISP. I heard that there is some way to use open ports to run voip traffic. Can any one guide me step by step how to do this in Quintum Tenor?
Thanks
Sam